# How can I have more than 2 directories deep with a controller in Kohana

Tags: php, url-routing, kohana-3.2

I have a stat, in which many can exist for an improvement, which is one model in my about page. I initially built the page as one giant controller having silly actions like "action_editimprovementstat".

So I tried to move things into directories, so rather than everything being in "[...]/controller/about", I moved things into there perspective folders, for example: "[...]/controller/about/improvement/stat"

I changed the regex of the route, so the controller would accept slashes, which judging by the debugger, worked, because now the controller text will show up as "about/improvement/stat", unfortunately it still tells me the requested url can't be found.

So, I ask, what is the simplest way to have a hierarchical controller structure?

Here is an example of controller URLs that I would prefer:
/about
/about/internal
/about/external
/about/improvement
/about/improvement/stat

Those would also have actions, so for example:
/about/improvement/edit/6
/about/improvement/stat/delete/7

I'm willing to compromise if there are issues with ambiguity.
(Btw, I think I could manage a way if I did my own routing through a single controller, but I'm wondering if there is a better way, or if that way is well documented [so I can learn from another's experience].)

Comment: I'm sorry to those who have read this. I don't think what i want is possible. I'm considering what to do instead. See the the second comment i made under Golez's post for more information.

I'm reevaluating what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add additional variables or constant values to the route if you live.

The [Kohana documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing) even shows a concrete example, where an extra directory is added in front of the route, which can have only one of two given values:

```
Route::set('sections', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))',
    array(
        'directory' => '(admin|affiliate)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Of course you can add values in the back or inbetween as well. The only requirement is that your route will always result in at least a controller and an action. But they don't actually have to exist in the url. You can specify routes that match other values and have a constant value for controller and/or action, like this:

```
Route::set('search', ':<query>', array('query' => '.*'))
  ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'search',
    'action' => 'index',
  ));
```

The greatest pitfall: It is important to understand that **routes are matched in the order they are added**, and as soon as a URL matches a route, routing is essentially "stopped" and *the remaining routes are never tried*. Because the default route matches almost anything, including an empty url, new routes must be place before it.
Maybe that is what's going wrong now?

Anyway, rather than adding trickery to match slashes, I'd rather create a route that accepts a large number of optional variables, so you could read 'urlpart1' to urlpartX' from your generic controller. That is, if you need to. The setup, of course, is to let you create different controllers for different urls, so you don't need a humongous controller with a gigantic method to decide what to do based on the url parts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I think I wasn't clear enough about what my issue truly was. I already setup the regex so the controller grabs multiple directories. The issue is the router has no idea how to turn those directories into a controller. I'm not sure what the router is trying to do in fact, just that it gets a 404.

For example, I will get the error "The requested URL about/view was not found on this server." Even though the an index action exists for the controller located at "Controller/about/view.php"

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what i want is even possible. You can't possibly greedily take everything up to the last 2 slashes for the controller, then grab the action, then be able to take the parameters like id past the next slash.

I'm reevaluating what to do... I don't want one giant controller, but having a hierarchical controller isn't possible.

Comment: OMG, I think i get it... the directory key may solve all my problems.

Give me another few minutes to verify by removing the dumbness from my brain.

Comment: My idea is impossible. The directories key would solve my problem if I didn't also want to have id as a suffix in a directory format.

So I can do my controller thing like "about/data/new" but I can't do "about/data/edit/7", because if I allow id, then about/data/new will be grabbed as:
Directory: "about", action: "data", id: "new"

Btw the issue is with my regex, which is greedy, not with grabbing a directory. If I made the directories static, or put the greedy portion at the end of the regex, then things would be fine.

Comment: It still won't work, even with directory and static directories... this is confusing me.
I'm getting a 404 and when i look at the arguments I see:     protected _directory => string(5) "about",
    protected _controller => string(4) "view",
    protected _action => string(5) "index",
    protected _uri => string(10) "about/view",

All of that makes sense, except the uri. The controller Controller_About_View exists at controller/about/view.php so I have no idea now why I'm getting a 404... Is their another argument or something I can look at it to debug this?

Comment: I'm closer. I got about/view/index to work. The issue was simply that I neglected to rename the view controller from About to About_View.
I believe there is an ambiguity issue with my higher hierarchies. I'm going to look into it now.

Comment: I'm going to compromise by just having an extra directory for less significant controllers that belong to a category of sorts. Like my about page, which has 4 models that need to be controlled.

I'm going to adjust my question a little, so your answer is relevant. My original question does not have a solution.

EDIT: on second thought, I'm gonna leave it open, just in case someone else knows some magical solution. I'll do what I said above, if their is no magical solution after a few more days.
Again, thanks for the answer, it did lead me to a compromise of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since I learned Kohana, my programming experience has been greatly improved because prior to Kohana I never gave a moments thought to how my urls were constructed. In the MVC world using Pretty URLs makes you really think about what you want to do and how to go about it.

In my opinion by looking at what you are wanting to do in the examples above, it seems to me that you are thinking backwards. You said the URLS that you preferred are: /about /about/internal /about/external /about/improvement /about/improvement/stat

It seems to me that "about" is really an action, not a controller. The url "/about/" is pretty confusing because it doesn't tell me what I'm getting information about but we can let that one slide because it's probably about the site in general. "/about/internal" is pretty clear but in a lot of ways you are trying to write your urls so that they read in proper English. In reality I would write them as: /about, /internal/about, /external/about, /improvement/about, /improvement_stat/about

I'm not sure why you are resisting have several controllers unless perhaps you are setting up your controllers as template controllers and maybe you think you have to do that for each one. You dont. In general I create a controller named "page" which is my template controller. Then all other controllers extend the page controller. I can define constants and other variables in the page controller that can be used in all the controllers that extend the page controller.

But if you are really resisiting writing multple controllers, you can always write specific routes that will let you reach any controller and action that you want. For example I used a route for a comparison where I wanted up to 4 id's passed into my route. I wrote that route like this:

```
Route::set('thing_compare', 'thing/compare/<thing1>/<thing2>(/<thing3>(/<thing4>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'thing',
        'action'     => 'compare'
    ));
```

Note that thing3 and thing4 are in parens which means they are optional. Then in my controller I can get those values by doing something like:

```
$thing1 = $this->request->param('thing1');
```

But going back to the examples you gave, just write the routes something like this (assuming your controller is named "about":

```
Route::set('about_internal', 'about/internal')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'about',
        'action'     => 'about_internal'
    ));
Route::set('about_external', 'about/external')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'about',
        'action'     => 'about_external'
    ))
```

Personally I would avoid setting routes like this and really reconsider how your urls need to be setup so that it creates a sensible design strategy.

Comment: I love how clear your explanation is. I also appreciate your answer, however I don't think you see how this would work.

How do I do data manipulations on about? About is apparently an action, but what action is it?

I implemented my about page before posting this; the reason I posted was that I wanted a better solution. the way it was and I think is currently done is I have an about controller and the following actions:
internalAddAction, internalEditAction, internalPostAction, internalDelAction, externalAddAction, ... , internalImprovementAdd, ... , internalImprovementDataAdd ...

Comment: If I put those into separate controllers, then I would have many controllers that have no obvious connection to a page. When is the "Improvement" controller used? What I want is a structure way to have these controllers be logically connected. Preferably with the route making sense with it, so my urls make sense [compared to "What effect will editing improvements have on my page again? Unfortunately the url just says /improvement/edit"].